# can't figure out array of hashes ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, nested

I am trying to turn an array of arrays into an array of hashes.  Could someone try to explain what I am exactly doing wrong here?  The first array within the array of arrays becomes the keys for the hash.  I can get the method to return one hash or even three of the same hashes.  But I can't get it return each different new hash within the final array.

```
table_data = [
  ["first_name", "last_name", "city", "state"],
  ["Elisabeth", "Gardenar", "Toledo", "OH"],
  ["Jamaal", "Du", "Sylvania", "OH"],
  ["Kathlyn", "Lavoie", "Maumee", "OH"]
]


def convert_table(table_array)
  hash = {}
  final_array = []
  headers_array = table_array.shift

  table_array.each_index do |x|
    i = 0
    until i == headers_array.length
      hash[headers_array[i]] = table_array[x][i]
      final_array << hash
      i += 1
    end
  end
  final_array
end

p convert_table(table_data)

#END GOAL
[ { "first_name" => "Elisabeth", "last_name" => "Gardenar", "city" => "Toledo", "state" => "OH" },
{ "first_name" => "Jamaal", "last_name" => "Du", "city" => "Sylvania", "state"    => "OH" },
{ "first_name" => "Kathlyn", "last_name" => "Lavoie", "city" => "Maumee", "state" => "OH" }
```

Comment: If you do speak English, please, read the following comment, which you are successfully ignoring forever:  
***I noticed you never accept the answers given to your questions. Make sure to go over your questions some time and accept the best answers given they solve your question. This way you let the community know, that the problem is solved and at the same time you reward the effort of the one, who has provided the solution. To accept the answer look for a checkmark under the answer score.***

Comment: No MCVE provided, no question stated. Downvoted.

Comment: I speak english.  I wasn't familiar with how this site works.  Now I am familiar and am going through my questions and picking the correct answer.  I see the value and necessity in doing so.  No need to TRY and insult.  If you want to be nit-picky about grammar, I would rephrase "successfully ignoring forever."  "Successfully" is present tense.  That's the farthest you can carry your statement.  "Forever" just doesn't work.  Next time you're asking if someone speaks english, nix that part.  Its vital while asking that question, to use perfectly clear english... forever (hehe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pair up keys (in `table_data[0]` and values (each other row in `table_data`) using `zip`, and map them to a hash:

```
table_data[1..-1].map { |values| Hash[table_data[0].zip(values)] }
```

EDIT: The part that doesn't work in your case is having one single hash that you keep reusing. When you do `final_array << hash`, it doesn't add a snapshot of the hash as it is then; it adds a *reference* to it. Thus, you don't have an array of three hashes, you have an array with three references to the same hash. You could avoid it by doing `final_array << hash.clone` to actually take a snapshot; or (much simpler) just make a new hash in each iteration of the loop (move `hash = {}` into the `table_array.each_index` loop).

Comment: thank you.  But could you tell me what wrong with my logic?  I figured my until loop would create every correct single hash... and it does.  Then the until ends.  But the each_index isn't done and stayed the same within the until loop.  Then the loop should make x (the index) = 1, and a new hash with the second person should be created.  Is my hash just getting overwritten each time?

Comment: Edited. For next time, please also describe what is wrong with your code, don't make us run it or analyse it just to find out what your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

As @Amadan has diagnosed your problem, I will suggest a more "Ruby-like" approach.

```
keys, *data = table_data
  #=> [["first_name", "last_name", "city", "state"],
  #    ["Elisabeth", "Gardenar", "Toledo", "OH"],
  #    ["Jamaal", "Du", "Sylvania", "OH"],
  #    ["Kathlyn", "Lavoie", "Maumee", "OH"]
  #   ]
keys
  #=> ["first_name", "last_name", "city", "state"] 
data
  #=> [["Elisabeth", "Gardenar", "Toledo", "OH"],
  #    ["Jamaal", "Du", "Sylvania", "OH"],
  #    ["Kathlyn", "Lavoie", "Maumee", "OH"]
  #   ] 

[keys].product(data).map { |pair| pair.transpose.to_h }
  #=> [{"first_name"=>"Elisabeth", "last_name"=>"Gardenar", "city"=>"Toledo", 
  #       "state"=>"OH"},
  #    {"first_name"=>"Jamaal", "last_name"=>"Du", "city"=>"Sylvania",
  #       "state"=>"OH"},
  #    {"first_name"=>"Kathlyn", "last_name"=>"Lavoie", "city"=>"Maumee",
  #       "state"=>"OH"}
  #   ]
```

The steps are as follows.

```
a = [keys].product(data)
  #=> [[["first_name", "last_name", "city", "state"],
  #     ["Elisabeth", "Gardenar", "Toledo", "OH"]
  #    ],
  #    [["first_name", "last_name", "city", "state"],
  #     ["Jamaal", "Du", "Sylvania", "OH"]],
  #    [["first_name", "last_name", "city", "state"],
  #     ["Kathlyn", "Lavoie", "Maumee", "OH"]
  #    ]
  #   ]
```

The first element of `a` is passed to `map`, the block variable `pair` is assigned and the block calculation is performed.

```
pair = a.first
  #=> [["first_name", "last_name", "city", "state"],
  #    ["Elisabeth", "Gardenar", "Toledo", "OH"]
  #   ] 
b = pair.transpose
  #=> [["first_name", "Elisabeth"],
  #    ["last_name", "Gardenar"],
  #    ["city", "Toledo"],
  #    ["state", "OH"]
  #   ] 
g = b.to_h
  #=> {"first_name"=>"Elisabeth", "last_name"=>"Gardenar", "city"=>"Toledo",
  #      "state"=>"OH"}
```

Therefore, `a.first` is mapped to `g`. The remaining calculations are similar.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has been properly answered by @CarySwoveland and @Amadan.

I'd just like to add that your table basically looks like a CSV table with header.

If your `table_data` does come from a file, you might as well read it directly with `CSV` :

```
csv_table = "first_name,last_name,city,state
Elisabeth,Gardenar,Toledo,OH
Jamaal,Du,Sylvania,OH
Kathlyn,Lavoie,Maumee,OH"

require 'csv'

CSV.parse(csv_table, headers: true).each do |row|
  p row
end
```

It outputs

```
#<CSV::Row "first_name":"Elisabeth" "last_name":"Gardenar" "city":"Toledo" "state":"OH">
#<CSV::Row "first_name":"Jamaal" "last_name":"Du" "city":"Sylvania" "state":"OH">
#<CSV::Row "first_name":"Kathlyn" "last_name":"Lavoie" "city":"Maumee" "state":"OH">
```

You can work [`CSV::Row`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html) as with an Hash.
If you really want a Hash, you can use `row.to_h` :

```
{"first_name"=>"Elisabeth", "last_name"=>"Gardenar", "city"=>"Toledo", "state"=>"OH"}
{"first_name"=>"Jamaal", "last_name"=>"Du", "city"=>"Sylvania", "state"=>"OH"}
{"first_name"=>"Kathlyn", "last_name"=>"Lavoie", "city"=>"Maumee", "state"=>"OH"}
```